# How can I create Frequency Matrix using all columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Let's say that I have a dataset that contains 4 binary columns for 2 rows.

It looks like this:

```
    c1 c2 c3 c4 c5
r1  0   1  0  1 0
r2  1   1  1  1 0
```

I want to create a matrix that gives the number of occurrences of a column, given that it also occurred in another column. Kinda like a confusion matrix

My desired output is:

```
   c1 c2  c3  c4 c5
c1  -  1   1   1  0
c2  1  -   1   2  0
c3  1  1   -   1  0
c4  1  2   1   -  0
```

I have used pandas crosstab but it only gives the desired output when using 2 columns. I want to use all of the columns

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### `dot`

```
df.T.dot(df)
# same as
# df.T @ df

    c1  c2  c3  c4  c5
c1   1   1   1   1   0
c2   1   2   1   2   0
c3   1   1   1   1   0
c4   1   2   1   2   0
c5   0   0   0   0   0
```

You can use `np.fill_diagonal` to make the diagonal zero

```
d = df.T.dot(df)
np.fill_diagonal(d.to_numpy(), 0)
d

    c1  c2  c3  c4  c5
c1   0   1   1   1   0
c2   1   0   1   2   0
c3   1   1   0   1   0
c4   1   2   1   0   0
c5   0   0   0   0   0
```

And as long as we're using Numpy, you could go all the way...

```
a = df.to_numpy()
b = a.T @ a
np.fill_diagonal(b, 0)

pd.DataFrame(b, df.columns, df.columns)

    c1  c2  c3  c4  c5
c1   0   1   1   1   0
c2   1   0   1   2   0
c3   1   1   0   1   0
c4   1   2   1   0   0
c5   0   0   0   0   0
```

Answer (score 3):

A way of using `melt` and `merge` with `groupby`

```
s=df.reset_index().melt('index').loc[lambda x : x.value==1]
s.merge(s,on='index').query('variable_x!=variable_y').groupby(['variable_x','variable_y'])['value_x'].sum().unstack(fill_value=0)
Out[32]: 
variable_y  c1  c2  c3  c4
variable_x                
c1           0   1   1   1
c2           1   0   1   2
c3           1   1   0   1
c4           1   2   1   0
```